# Display two values visually into a bar

Tags: jquery, charts

I'm trying to create a function which takes 2 values as parameters and displays them in a bar (, constant width) so they fill the bar based on their ratio.

I hope the code (on the link below) explains that better.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXeZKO

**JS**

```
// bar's width is constantly 200px
var lengthOfBar = 200;

// what I want is to display the values visually into the bar
// the divs (line 8 and 9) should fill the 200px width altogether
function range(val1, val2) {
     var exp = val1/200;
     var inc = val2/200;

     $("#bar").append("<div class='b' style='width:" + exp  +"px'></div>");
     $("#bar").append("<div class='c' style='width:" + inc  +"px'></div>");
}

range(1400, 762);
```

**HTML is just this**

```
<div id="bar"></div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Imgonzalves It works but it does not fill the whole #bar. I posted the code in the comments below which works as supposed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the percentage of the length by doing `val1 / (val1 + val2)` (for each value) and base the calculation of the length from there:

```
var lengthOfBar = 200;

function range(val1, val2) {
    var percentage1 = val1 / (val1 + val2);
    var percentage2 = val2 / (val1 + val2);

    $("#bar").append("<div class='b' style='width:" + lengthOfBar * percentage1 + "px'></div>");
    $("#bar").append("<div class='c' style='width:" + lengthOfBar * percentage2 + "px'></div>");
}

range(1400, 762);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m41q379g/)

Comment: Seems much cleaner than my first solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it was indeed easy to figure that out. This way it works as it should.

```
// bar's width is constantly 200px
var lengthOfBar = 200;

// what I want is to display the values visually into the bar
// the divs (line 8 and 9) should fill the 200px width altogether
function range(val1, val2) {
     var exp = val1/200;
     var inc = val2/200;
     var ratio = exp + inc;
     var part = 200/ratio;
     $("#bar").append("<div class='b' style='width:" + (part*exp)  +"px'></div>");
     $("#bar").append("<div class='c' style='width:" + (part*inc)  +"px'></div>");
}

range(1400, 762);
```